# Deconvolution layer in caffe

Tags: caffe, deconvolution

After some reading about deconvolution in caffe, I am confused about the FCN's train.prototx [here](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/pascalcontext-fcn32s/train.prototxt). The deconvolution layer's default weight filler is 'constant' and default value is zero. According to the deconvolution operation in caffe, doesn't all the output is zero in that input are multiplied by zero.

Answer (score 1):

This model used pretrained parameters for initialization. You should use 'xavier' filler ([mnist model](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet.prototxt)):

```
weight_filler {
  type: "xavier"
}
bias_filler {
  type: "constant"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right, the inference of a FCN initialised with Zero Deconv weights would be zero. You don't want that.

Initialising a deconv layer with `weight_filler:{type:"bilinear"}` would be appropriate. That would initialise the filter weights to a bilinear filer of required size.